# How to send message to user when he connects to spring websocket

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket

I want to send message to user when he connects to spring websocket, I've

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private GenervicSerice<User> userService;
    @Autowired 
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template; 
    private CurrentUser currnetUser;
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/", "/exchange/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {

        registration.setInterceptors(myChannelInterception());
        try {
            updateNotificationAndBroadcast();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public MyChannelInterception myChannelInterception() {
        return new MyChannelInterception();
    }


    private void updateNotificationAndBroadcast() {    
        try {               
            template.convertAndSend("/queue/notify", "Greetings");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error message is " + e.getMessage() + "\n\n\n" + "Caused by " + e.getCause()
                    );
        }

    }

}
```

MyChannelInterception class is

```
public class ImtehanChannelInterception extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {     

    private CurrentUser currnetUser;

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

        MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
        SimpMessageType type = (SimpMessageType) headers.get("simpMessageType");
        String simpSessionId = (String) headers.get("simpSessionId");
        currnetUser = new CurrentUser();
        if (type == SimpMessageType.CONNECT) {
            Principal principal = (Principal) headers.get("simpUser");
            currnetUser.setCurrentUserEmail(principal.getName());
            System.out.println("WsSession " + simpSessionId
                    + " is connected for user " + principal.getName());
        } else if (type == SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT) {
            System.out.println("WsSession " + simpSessionId
                    + " is disconnected");
        }

        return message;
    }

}
```

through this I get information about new connected user but the method `updateNotificationAndBroadcast()` in `WebSocketConfig` is not sending messages to new logged-in users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create `SessionSubscribeEvent` listener and use `SimpMessagingTemplate` inside.

Btw, `configureClientInboundChannel` is called only once (not for every user connected). So you have to handle sending message inside interceptor.

Try something like this:

```
@Service
public class SomeSubscribeListener {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public SomeSubscribeListener(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleSubscribeEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
        template.convertAndSendToUser(event.getUser().getName(), "/queue/notify", "GREETINGS");
    }
}
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Any example or resource on the Net please, that act would be a life saving one. I've spent three days on that issue, but could not get job done, please help in this case.

Comment: Updated with the example

Comment: Please add `)` at the end of __"GREETINGS";__

Comment: Thanks that was I looking for, it raised an other issue,but that is gonna be a new question, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can subscribe on more events, check the docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-appplication-context-events

Answer (score 1):

you need a Websocketconfig file:

```
package mx.config.ws;
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
   @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
       registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS()
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    ...
    }
}
```

And declare a nother @Configuration file:

```
package mx.config.ws;
@Configuration
public class WebSocketHandlersConfig {

    @Bean
    public StompConnectEvent webSocketConnectHandler() {
        return new StompConnectEvent();
    }

    @Bean
    public StompDisconnectEvent webSocketDisconnectHandler() {
        return new StompDisconnectEvent();
    }
}
```

Next create implementation of ApplicationListener interface. Automatically you will intercept the STOMP connections

```
package mx.config.ws;
public class StompConnectEvent implements ApplicationListener<SessionConnectEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectEvent event) {

         StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

         System.out.println("StompConnectEvent::onApplicationEvent()    sha.getSessionId(): "+sha.getSessionId()+" sha.toNativeHeaderMap():"+sha.toNativeHeaderMap());


         //String  company = sha.getNativeHeader("company").get(0);
         //logger.debug("Connect event [sessionId: " + sha.getSessionId() +"; company: "+ company + " ]");



         // HERE YOU CAN MAYBE SEND A MESSAGE

    }

}
```

Check this link for a bout of information:
http://www.sergialmar.com/2014/03/detect-websocket-connects-and-disconnects-in-spring-4/

Answer (score 1):

The Spring documentation indicates that you need to implement Spring's Application Listener interface.

[26. WebSocket Support -> 26.4.14 Events and Interception](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-appplication-context-events)

The following code is an example for the Session Susbscribe event. you can find all the possible events in the link provided, including the connect event.

```
@Component
public class VSignNewSubscriptionsListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionSubscribeEvent> {
@Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
  }
}
```