# How to get user sessionid , requested url to subscribe and user information during a websocket call using spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am currently working on an application which is using websocket with stomp , sockjs, spring-mvc , spring-security.

The problem which I am facing is that ,after I have made a websocket call using stomp and sockjs from the UI (javascript part) I may not get the response at the same moment ,i.e, the response can be async .Now the backend code from spring mvc need to know the below three information for sending the data back to the UI to that particular user only who has requested for it

- sessionid of the user who has actually requested for the resource
- user whom to send the data
- destination url.

The above 3 information will be needed for the below code to send the response from any class.

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("username", </queue/destination-url>, dataToSend, sesionId of the requesting user for constructing the header);
```

I have already tried using the below methods:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId()
```

but both of these gives **`NPE`** in the class were I need to send back the data.
So, I wanted to know if there is a way I can get these information using spring-security or if there is any other way to implement this.

Please let me know if you need any other information.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could catch `SessionConnectedEvent` inside your event listener. I explained how to do it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340271/how-to-send-message-to-user-when-he-connects-to-spring-websocket/37387917#37387917)

This is the excerpt from [Spring Websocket documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-appplication-context-events):

> SessionConnectEvent — published when a new STOMP CONNECT is received indicating the start of a new client session. The event contains the message representing the connect including the session id, user information (if any), and any custom headers the client may have sent. This is useful for tracking client sessions. Components subscribed to this event can wrap the contained message using SimpMessageHeaderAccessor or StompMessageHeaderAccessor.

It looks like you will be able to extract all the information you need and store it somewhere.